# What is the right way to use Ecmascript 6 arrow functions as methods in classes?

Tags: javascript, function, class, arrow-functions

Ecmascript 6 arrow functions seem ideally suited to be used as methods in classes since they are not subject to the calling context messing with the "this" reference. I can't see how to use them the way I expect, though. The following is a class which shows two ways I can see to use them:

```
class Person {

constructor(aName) {
    this.name = aName;
    this.say2 = () => console.log(this.name);
}

say() { console.log(this.name) }

say3() { () => consolve.log(this.name) }

}
```

Both say2 and say3 will use the new this handling and one should be able to pass them to click handlers, and other functions needing callbacks and not have to worry about the callback being invoked in some what whiich causes "this" to unexpectedly point to something other than the appropriate instance of the object.

Both say2 and say3 seem awkward, though. say2 is defined in the constructor and say3 is really a wrapper around an arrow functions. I was expecting some sytax which would allow me to replace the say() line with something like

```
say: () => console.log(this.name)
```

But as near as I can tell, you cannot do anything like this. So the question is, to use arrow functions as methods is the approach of say2 or say3 reasonable. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

In the ES6 grammar, [the body of a class](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-class-definitions) may only consist of [method definitions](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-method-definitions), so arrow function expressions are not permitted here. This is a simplified snippet of the relevant portions of the grammar:

```
ClassBody :
    ClassElementList

ClassElementList :
    ClassElement
    ClassElementList ClassElement

ClassElement :
    MethodDefinition
    static MethodDefinition
    ;

MethodDefinition :
    PropertyName ( StrictFormalParameters ) { FunctionBody }
    GeneratorMethod
    get PropertyName ( ) { FunctionBody }
    set PropertyName ( PropertySetParameterList ) { FunctionBody }
```

So in your example:

```
class Person {

    constructor(aName) {
        this.name = aName;
        this.say2 = () => console.log(this.name);
    }

    say() { console.log(this.name) }

    say3() { () => console.log(this.name) }

}
```

- `say` is a normal method definition, which suffers from the same issues with `this` binding as normal functions. However, you can get around that using `bind` when you pass it, as in `element.addEventListener('click', this.say.bind(this));`.
- `say2` will work, but you lose the convenience of specifying methods outside of the constructor.
- `say3` won't work - while it is syntactically valid, it will be parsed as a method, whose body consists of a single arrow function. To clarify, `say3() { () => console.log(this.name) }` and `say3() { return () => console.log(this.name) }` differ in that the former will do nothing and return `undefined`, whereas the latter will return an arrow function expression which, when called, will print to the console.